# How to generate random cube

Tags: python, mesh

Can we create generate cube. When we duplicate cube should generate but random side . like we can generate random color.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you're looking to do? What do you want to happen when a new cube is generated?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I want to have a copy of cube but of different size shape. Always i have to take a new cube scale down or scale up etc. im make a low poly building. So if i just duplicate the cube i can have various shape in few seconds. Then i can uvwrap etc.

Comment: Just to be precise, a "cube" with different sized faces or different shape is no longer a cube, but a cuboid or some other kind of object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to use a *Random Transform*. It doesn't cause the object to transform as it is being duplicated, but you can apply it to multiple objects after they have been duplicated.

First, make a bunch of duplicates of something, select them all, and select random transform.

[image: Duplicates]

Play with the values, until they are sufficiently random.

[image: TransformRandom]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect thats what i need. Thanks